# Error while reading greeting packet on connection of php with mysql using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'votesystem','8080');

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

Errors returned are:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=14576 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\votesystem\admin\includes\conn.php on line 2

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\votesystem\admin\includes\conn.php on line 2

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\votesystem\admin\includes\conn.php on line 2

**My localhost runs on port 8080.**

- username-root
- hostname=localhost
- password=no
- global privileges=ALL
- PRIVILEGES Grant= yes

Comment: try changing your connect string to `new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root'....`

Comment: its not working @gview

Comment: Why is your mysql running on port 8080?  Is that a mistake?  Remove the port '8080' from the connect string.  It looks like you don't understand the difference between a webserver and the mysql server, which by default runs on port 3306

Comment: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ I need to run my MySql on port 8080 . Simply on localhost earlier neither my Apache nor Xampp was working so I changed my port to 8080

Comment: Exactly.  That is your WEBSERVER.  Phpmyadmin is a web application that is connecting to a mysql server.  Try `$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'votesystem', '3306');`

Comment: ok let me try . Seems I got confused

Comment: The page which I am trying to connect is an admin page after writting above query when i am trying to login it is showing incorrect password but I am simply copying pasting it from the table in votesystem database

Comment: So the error has now changed!  You are making progress.  Does your root mysql account really have no password set?  You are using that account to try and connnect.  What is the new exact error you are seeing?

Comment: yes there's no password set

Comment: I am trying to login into the system using admin user id and password but after filling the credentials it is showing incorrect credentials

Comment: So you are now connecting to mysql, or you are still getting a connection error?

Comment: connection is done

Comment: Ok, so this is a new problem, where we need to see the code that is not working.  You need to make a new question for that, and include the relevant code.  ;)

Comment: its done now Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused the Webserver with the MySQL Server.  Your web server is running on port 8080, not your MySQL Server.  The MySQL server runs on port 3306 (by default) so your web application needs to connect to it on that port.

Change your mysqli connect string to:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'votesystem', '3306');
```